# Google charts с видоискателем

Tags: javascript, график, визуализация, google-chart

Подскажите, как построить с помощью Google charts график из видоискателем по времени типа http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html или https://finance.i.ua/ (график курса валют)
Хотелось также иметь возможность быстрого переключения (выбора диапазона в нижней части графика) - данные за 1мес, 3мес, 1год

Подскажите, где это можно прочитать или посмотреть?

Может быть ещё есть какие-нибудь бесплатные библиотеки для таких решений?
[image: Пример, как оно должно быть]

Comment: Тут у Вас используется точно HighStock. Реализация совсем не сложная, но в ответ пример запихнуть будет сложно, так как необходимо установить библиотеку `Highstock` Без него работать не будет. Вот статья, где подробно описано, как сделать http://unboxit.ru/blog/63-risuem-grafiki-highcharts-highstock-po-dannym-iz-mysql.html   Если же Вы хотите именно через Google Charts, то посмотрите эту статью про линейные графики https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, вас заинтересует Google [Annotation Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart). Это семейство timeline charts, яркий представитель [Annotated Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline).

Примечательно, что я бы не стал искать на слово "видоискатель", а ограничился бы "timeline chart zoom". Как сказано в комментариях, у d3 такой тип диаграмм называется "brush".

Примечательным является и то, что к каждой серии данных (поставляются в колонках относительно дат) можно передать аннотации с заголовком и примечанием.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В остальном, кроме настройки масштаба и заливки диаграмма не выделяется. Работает очень быстро даже с минутными тикерами.

Живой пример

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"
></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['annotationchart'] });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Kepler-22b mission');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler title');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler text');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Gliese 163 mission');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Gliese title');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Gliese text');
    data.addRows([
      [
        new Date(2314, 2, 15),
        12400,
        undefined,
        undefined,
        10645,
        undefined,
        undefined
      ],
      [
        new Date(2314, 2, 16),
        24045,
        'Lalibertines',
        'First encounter',
        12374,
        undefined,
        undefined
      ],
      [
        new Date(2314, 2, 17),
        35022,
        'Lalibertines',
        'They are very tall',
        15766,
        'Gallantors',
        'First Encounter'
      ],
      [
        new Date(2314, 2, 18),
        12284,
        'Lalibertines',
        'Attack on our crew!',
        34334,
        'Gallantors',
        'Statement of shared principles'
      ],
      [
        new Date(2314, 2, 19),
        8476,
        'Lalibertines',
        'Heavy casualties',
        66467,
        'Gallantors',
        'Mysteries revealed'
      ],
      [
        new Date(2314, 2, 20),
        0,
        'Lalibertines',
        'All crew lost',
        79463,
        'Gallantors',
        'Omniscience achieved'
      ]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(
      document.getElementById('chart_div')
    );

    var options = {
      displayAnnotations: true
    };

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 630px; height: 183px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: в d3 похожий функционал почему-то называется "brush"

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, видимо, со стандартизацией чартов вообще все плохо =)